# php proc_open doesn't send ouput immediately to the browser

Tags: php

i'm using php script with proc_open to get a shell ouput immediatly on the browser.
this work in cli but not via web 
here's my script:

```
//$arr_pipes = array( );

$str_command = './something.sh';


$descriptorspec = array(

    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout -> we use this
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr 

);

//   0 => array( "file", "php://stdin", "r" ),   // stdin is a file that the child will read from
//   1 => array( "file", "php://stdout", "w" ),  // stdout is a file that the child will write to
//   2 => array( "file", "/dev/null", "w" )      // stderr is a file that the child will write to



$process = @proc_open( $str_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes );
//$process = proc_open( $str_command, $descriptorspec, $arr_pipes);



if ( is_resource( $process ) )

{

 while( ! feof($pipes[1]))

    {
        $return_message = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
        if (strlen($return_message) == 0) break;
        echo "<pre>$return_message</pre>";
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: It's rather odd you're using proc_open without sending data - exec or passthru might be better alternatives if you don't need to send data to the process. But with regard to proc_open, depending on how your target command/process behaves you may need to close the STDIN connection before it begins its work (so it knows not to expect any more input). And you should close the STDOUT and STDERR connections before closing the process or it might hang while it waits for everything to be clean before shutting down as well.

Comment: thanks,can you link a reference to a simple passthru script that combines shell_exec.

Comment: @user2131714 Care to be more specific about how you fixed it? I think I was busy that day so I couldn't be there with you ;)